# Android 日本語ファイルの読み込みに失敗する

Tags: android, 日本語

Android ローカルにHTMLファイルを保存したい考えています。
日本語ファイルを保存しようとするとファイル名が変換され、次のsFileName
で保存がされます。

WebViewにてそのファイルを読み込もうとすると
エラーがでて、ファイルの読み込みに失敗します。

保存するファイル名

```
sFileName = "aatyu_tag_%E3%83%A1%E3%83%80%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%83%88.html"
```

ファイルパス

```
filePath = "file:///data/data/(名前空間)/files/aatyu_tag_%E3%83%A1%E3%83%80%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%83%88.html"

//次にように読み込むます
myWebView.loadUrl(filePath);
```

次のようなエラーがでます

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png", source: data:text/html,chromewebdata (12)

Comment: 確認はしていませんが`WebView.loadUrl`の代わりに`WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL` はどうでしょうか。
[こちら](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997146/kitkat-kills-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file-android-asset-webkit-a)に類似の質問があります。